# Piecewise function $f(x,y)$ - Limits and Continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Consider the function $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by:

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x < 0,\\ x\cdot y &\text{if } x \geq 0 \text{ and }y \geq 0,\\-x &\text{if } x \geq 0 \text{ and }y < 0.\end{cases}$$

Describe the properties of this function in terms of limits and continuity.

I am struggling to see which limits I should be taking and how to check if $f(x,y)$ is continuous. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Sorry for my edit, I was editing and didn't see that you edit first. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Cortizol No worries, that happens from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane is divided into $3$ parts for $f$, with borders the $y$-axis (that is, $x=0$) and the right wing of the $x$-axis (that is, $y=0\,\land\,x\ge 0$).

Continuity of $f$ *elsewhere* is obvious, so it remains to check *all the border points*, probably the origin needs a separate dealing. So, for example pick a point on the right wing of $x$-axis, $(x,0)$ with $x>0$. Then, if a sequence  of points $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(x,0)$, will $f(x_n,y_n)$ always have (the same) limit?

[image]

Comment: Yes if you could add picture, that would be great.

Comment: Are there any limits I can take to show that f is not continuous?

Comment: Good picture, thanks. Note that the $z$-axis has a much smaller scaling than the other ones, and in reality the angle enclosed by the grey and the green pieces of planes is $45^\circ$.